# Title Columns shows up twice in the edit or new form

Tags: 2007, content-type

current setup: 
1. Parent content type (PCT1) has 5 columns (including Title column)
2. Child content type (CCT1-A) inherites from PCT1 and adds 5 more columns (but child ct also comes with it's own Title column).
3. Now I associates Child control type to a document library.
4. I see two titles in the edit item or new item page
5. If i disable (hide) any one of the Title column (either in parent or child ct. NOT hiding from both CT) then both titles dissappears from edit or new page
6. What are my solution?
7. I must have the Title column but it seems each CT is bringing it's own Title

Please suggest.

Answer (score 1):

Can I ask why you included another Title column in the child content type? Surely you could just inherit the Title column from the parent.

Either way, the duplication of the Title site column in your child content type is probably responsible for the behaviour you're seeing.

If you do indeed need another Title column in the child content type, I'd strongly suggested creating a brand new Site Column and associating that with the child content type, and giving it a display name of Title and an internal name of something more unique/distinct.

Comment: I did not include the title column; it comes with the content type. I only need 1 Title column. Title column comes with the CT. So parent had one and child had 1. Now the new CT has 2 Title Column.

Comment: My apologies, I misunderstood. So your parent CT has Title, and your child inherits so includes Title, but you're seeing a second Title column appear? If you access the site column via the content type edit page, can you see if the two have different GUIDs?

Comment: I only see one Title column in the Child Content type. I only see one Title column in the Parent Content Type. The ctype is same for these 2 columns.